# Select from table A and B, where records from table A and table B don't exist in table C?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm having trouble visualising the setup for a query I'd like to create.

I have table A (users) and table B (events). For every event, I would like a list of users who did NOT attend.

I imagine a third table is necessary, associating the users with the events, containing both the user and event ID. If a user and event ID combination is absent from the table, the user did not attend.

How would my query need to look in order to return a list of every user who did not attend each event?

Alternatively I could query the events table, loops through the results, and for each event I could query the users who do not have a record with matching event ID in the third table. This seems inefficient and obviously wrong, as many additional db calls are made.

```
foreach ($getEvents as $v) {
    SELECT userID FROM users WHERE userID NOT IN (SELECT userID FROM tableC WHERE eventID = '".$v["eventID"]."');
}
```

Happy to provide more information if necessary.

Comment: What information are in the users table and in the events table? Are there any corresponding fields?

Comment: No relationship between the events table and users table. Assume userID and eventID the only fields in each table (the other fields are unrelated).

Comment: @NickDawes There has to be a relationship between users events somewhere, otherwise your question cannot be answered.  The `C` table appears to be a junction table between users and the events they attend.

Comment: Apologies @TimBiegeleisen, I have not yet created the third table so at this stage no relationship exists. Creating the third table would introduce the relationship, but then how would I query the database to get the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just wanted a list of users who did not attend a single event, we could just left join the users table to the junction table `C` and be done.  However, since you want a report for all events we need a different approach.  One option is to use a calendar table which represents every user's relation to every event.  We can generate this table via a cross join between the user and event tables.  Then, left join this calendar table to the junction table `C`.

```
SELECT t1.userID, t1.eventID
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT u.id AS userID, e.id AS eventID
    FROM users u
    CROSS JOIN events e
) t1
LEFT JOIN tableC t2
    ON t1.userID = t2.userID AND
       t1.eventID = t2.eventID
WHERE t2.userID IS NULL;
```

Comment: This solution would be perfect if I wanted to query for users who did not attend a specific event, however I would like to return a list of users for every event in the events table. The result set would look like this...

    eventID    userID
    1               1
    1               2
    1               3
    2               1

Which would suggest users 1, 2 and 3 did not attend event 1, but users 2 and 3 attended event 2.

Comment: Hey Tim, I see you've edited your reply- any chance you could explain the query?

Comment: Gordon gave a similar answer.  The basic idea is to cross join users and events.  This gives a table which is a list of every event and user.  Then left join this with `C` and retain only rows where a certain user/event was not a match.

Comment: I get it! So Cross Join creates a table of every possible user/event combination, and the rest of the query simply scans the third table for matches. The records that don't match show that the user didn't attend the event, as there is no record in the third table.  I'll set this up quickly then close the question.

Comment: Yes, so you're missing the junction table `C` and then you need a cross join for the calendar table.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle this by generating *all* user/event combinations.  *Then*, filter out the ones that do exist:

```
select e.event_id, u.user_id
from events e cross join
     users u left join
     userevents ue
     on ue.event_id = e.event_id and ue.user_id = u.user_id
where ue.event_id is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query !

```
SELECT
         e.event_id     AS 'Event ID'   , 
         u.user_id      AS 'User ID' 
    FROM
         events         e               ,
         users          u 
    WHERE 
          e.event_id NOT IN (SELECT event_id FROM userevents)
    AND   
          u.user_id  NOT IN (SELECT user_id FROM users)
```